# .NET MVC Server_GetLastError always returns missing view error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I'm trying to implement global unhandled exception logging in MVC 3. I've set up my web.config like so..

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/error/http500"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error/http404"/>
</customErrors>
```

When I trigger an exception for the controller, it redirects to the error page as expected. The problem is, when I use `Server.GetLastError()` in Global.asax, the exception is always

```
"The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Views/deanslist/Error.aspx\r\n~/Views/deanslist/Error.ascx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx\r\n~/Views/deanslist/Error.cshtml\r\n~/Views/deanslist/Error.vbhtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml"
```

I was expecting it to provide the actual exception that was thrown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the following line from your Global.asax:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

The `HandleError` attribute intercepts all exceptions in Release mode and attempts to render the `Error.cshtml` view. You probably have deleted this view from the `~/Views/Shared` folder and so when an unhandled exception is thrown this exception handler intercepts the exception and attempts to render an non-existent view.